# Buried treasure, is there a list?

Tags: jagged-alliance-2

I'm playing on the jagged alliance 2 [1.13 fanpatch/mod](http://ja2v113.pbworks.com/w/page/4218339/FrontPage). (But that should not matter in this case). And I have a metal detector. The description says it could find items buried underground. While I understand it can find hidden mines, but can it also find other items hidden underground.

Is this actually true? Is there a list of items you can find? And locations? Or is it just random?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No the metal detector can only be used to look for mines in Jagged Alliance 2.

From the [wiki](http://jaggedalliance.wikia.com/wiki/Metal_Detector):

> Used to identifying land mines. In Jagged Alliance, several sectors
>   contain buried items and treasures that can only be found using the
>   metal detector

Comment: Right, do you perhaps know if the mod adds the possibility of finding hidden items?

Comment: No the mod does not allow you to find hidden items.